# Laravel Eloquent - Retrieve the first value of a OneToMany relationship by the foreignKey

Tags: laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I Have two tables, materials and quotations, each material can have many quotations, a quotation can have only a material.

***materials***

```
id | description
---+------------
 1 | Steel
 2 | Copper
```

***quotations***

```
id | value | material_id |      created_at     |     updated_at
---+-------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------
 1 | 15.26 |      1      | 2014-12-12 16:10:08 | 2014-12-12 16:10:08
 2 |  5.33 |      2      | 2014-12-12 16:10:08 | 2014-12-12 16:10:08
 3 | 15.22 |      1      | 2014-12-12 16:15:08 | 2014-12-12 16:15:08
 4 |  5.21 |      2      | 2014-12-12 16:15:08 | 2014-12-12 16:15:08
 5 | 15.15 |      1      | 2014-12-12 16:20:08 | 2014-12-12 16:20:08
 6 |  5.16 |      2      | 2014-12-12 16:20:08 | 2014-12-12 16:20:08
 7 | 15.01 |      1      | 2014-12-12 16:25:08 | 2014-12-12 16:25:08
 8 |  5.00 |      2      | 2014-12-12 16:25:08 | 2014-12-12 16:25:08
```

And this is the related model, one file models/Material.php

```
class Material extends Eloquent {
  public function quotations() {
    return $this->hasMany('Quotation');
  }
}

class Quotation extends Eloquent {
  public function material() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Material');
  }
}
```

**What I want to Do**

I would like to retrieve in a blade template the last quotation saved, that belongs to a specific material. Let's say steel, and would like to use the ORM.

```
{{ Quotation::where('material_id', '=', 1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first()->value }}
```

This is what I did to retrieve it but I would like to say "*Where material = steel*" not using the material_id field.

So I tried to use eager loading, but don't like to use eager costraints in the blade template, and anyway for what I read it doesn't seem to be the right way.

I tried this:

```
{{ Material::first()->quotations->first()->value }}
```

but I still cannot specify the material by its description (I use the first() method) and retrieve the first row in the table, the oldest value instead of the newer one.

There's a way to use the ORM power without having to use a raw query or a very long builded query?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can work with the relation like any other query:

```
Material::first()->quotations()->where(..)->orderBy(..)->first()->value;
```

But you can do even more - say you'd like to eager load the above for multiple materials. Then that code wouldn't be of any help and you would end up with querying `quotations` table per every `material`. Luckily you can use something else:

```
// Material
public function latestQuotation()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Quotation')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
}
```

then simply:

```
Material::first()->latestQuotation;

// or eager load
$materials = Material::with('latestQuotation')->get();
$materials->first()->latestQuotation;
```

Read more here: http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

Comment: Thanks @JarekTkaczyk I'll go deeper in eager loading, so I can use `with` even with a public function setted in the model, interesting. But in this case how to specify the metal that the quotation belongs? Should I create a function for every material? E.g. for steel `return $this->hasOne('Quotation')->where('material_id','=',1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');`

And in both case (eager and not eager) can I specify directly the material by its description (steel, copper) and not by its id? I thought that once setted up the relations in the model I could use even the columns from the other table

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. 1 You can use `with` in case of relations, and the one I showed is a relation. 2 If you want to define 1 relation per material, then you can do so, however it's not the best for sure - if you add new material, what then? Use `whereHas` and `with` in order to set constraints on the related table.

Comment: I'm not sure What you mean. I would like to query `SELECT q.value FROM quotations q LEFT JOIN materials m ON (m.id=q.material_id) WHERE m.description='steel' ORDER BY q.updated_at DESC LIMIT 0,1` Now I think once setted up the relations in the model I could use something like this: `Quotation::with('decription','=','gold')->orderBy('created_up','desc')->first()` I know this specific code doesn't work, I wrote just to explain the logic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using Wherehas: `public function getLastQuotation($material) {$quotation = Quotation::whereHas('material', function($query) use($material) {$query->where('description',$material);})->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first(); return $quotation->value; }` (Sorry I'm not able to format the code in the comment :() And then calling it: `$quotation->getLastQuotation('steel')` It does work (Thanks @Jarek for your suggestions) but this generate this query (...continue on next comment...)

Comment: (...Continue from previous comment...)
`select * from quotations where (select count(*) from materials where quotations.material_id = materials.id and description = 'steel') >= 1 order by updated_at desc limit 1` That is a little bit complex than the one I wanted `SELECT q.value FROM quotations q LEFT JOIN materials m ON (m.id=q.material_id) WHERE m.description='steel' ORDER BY q.updated_at DESC LIMIT 0,1`